# add class depending on condition to html via python

Tags: html, django, django-templates, jinja2

the following code is the one I am using for the header on all the templates of my site and adding it to each of them with:
`{% include 'header.html' %}`

I am trying to figure out how to add class="active" to the links on my header in order for it to highlight the corresponding nav-item depending on the current page. I was trying to define a function that returned different values depending on which template was active but I dont think I defined it correctly because when I put the condition inside the html it threw an error. Should I use the jinja tags inside the class attribute or outside the whole  tags. Also, how can I know which is the current template. Pease help, thanks!

```
{% load static %}
<header role="banner">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand " href="{% url 'main:index' %}">my site</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExample05" aria-controls="navbarsExample05" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExample05">
        <ul class="navbar-nav pl-md-5 ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="{% url 'main:index' %}">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'main:about' %}">Nosotros</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="projects.html">Ingeniería</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="{% url 'main:services' %}" id="dropdown04" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Servicios</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown04">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="services.html">Diseño</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="services.html">Impresión 3D</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="services.html">Mantenimiento</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="blog.html">Tienda</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'main:contact' %}">Contáctenos</a>
          </li>
        </ul>


      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: You want to add the class to the `<li class="nav-item">` or the `<a>` tag?

Comment: sorry if I was unclear, I was referring to the whole item but I want to add it to the <a> tag

Comment: Why are you using `href="projects.html"`? Isn't there a view for this template? I believe there should be a [TemplateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/base/#templateview) that just renders the `projects.html` template and returns as response. I'm asking this because I see no way to achieve template processing when accessing tab "Ingeniería".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I like to do is pass essential page information using `urls.py` and `kwargs`. For example, the page Title, the page name, and some other keywords. Let's say we have two pages, page1 and page2.

**urls.py**

In urls.py we define the page views and set their key words.

```
urlpatterns += [path('page1/', page1_view,  kwargs = {'navbar': 'page1'})]
urlpatterns += [path('page2/', page2_view,  kwargs = {'navbar': 'page2'})]
```

**views.py**

In views we need to make sure the kwargs are passed to the template. The only thing you need to add is `**kwarg` to your view

```
def page2(request, **kwargs):
    return render(request, 'page2.html')
```

**header.html**

In the header.html template we can set it up so that depending on the `navbar` kwarg we get the right page showing as active.

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link {% if request.resolver_match.kwargs.navbar == 'page1' %}active{% endif %}" href="/page1">Page1</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link {% if request.resolver_match.kwargs.navbar == 'page2' %}active{% endif %}" href="/page2">Page2</a>
</li>
```

Of course, you could clean this up by using snippets and loops.

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer it worked! I was missing kwargs.